# UIImageView with ScaleAspectFit mode makes image pixelated

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3

I'd like to show an image in a UIImageView. The image is bigger than the UIImageView, so I set the contentMode like this:

```
previewImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

The problem now is that it looks pixelated like ...

[image]

but should look like ...

[image]

I remember that back in the days with Swift 2.3 and Xcode 7.x on iOS 9.x it looked "correct".

Any ideas?

**Edit**:

If I set the heightConstraint.constant of the UIImageView to 49.5 in viewDidLoad() the image is scaled correct without pixelation.

I should also mention that the UIImageView was created in the InterfaceBuilder. Is there any known bug?

Comment: What's the differences between the two images?

Comment: The first one is pixelated, the difference is more visible on the real device and in the simulator.

Comment: did you find a solution? have this all over my app

Answer (score -1):

Set content mode to 'Aspect fit' and 
Just resize your original image to lower size and it will work for u!